# How to set up Maven for Android projects in a Mac OSX environment?

Tags: android

Despite my research in trying to find resources that describe how to set Maven up on Mac OSX to work with Android projects,
I've been unable to find a site which describes me about Maven for android projects from scratch level in Mac OSX environment.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot set environmental variables for maven, android, java.. etc.